# hibernate.search.lucene_version was not specified: using LUCENE_CURRENT

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search with Spring Boot. I do not have any special configuration for Hibernate Search. It just shows that warning on application startup. How can I specify hibernate.search.lucene_version?

My SearchService class (the only place Hibernate Search is used):

```
@Service
public class SearchService {

    private FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager;
    private QueryBuilder queryBuilder;

    @Autowired
    public SearchService(EntityManager entityManager) {
        entityManager = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() throws InterruptedException {
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Post.class).get();
    }

    public List<Post> searchByQuery(String query) {
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.phrase()
                .withSlop(5)
                .onField("title")
                .sentence(query)
                .createQuery();
        Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Post.class);
        return (List<Post>) jpaQuery.setMaxResults(20).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Spring Boot configuration file, prefix any Hibernate ORM/Hibernate Search property with `spring.jpa.properties.`.

So in an `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.lucene_version LATEST
```

In an `application.yaml` file:

```
spring.jpa.properties:
    hibernate.search:
        lucene_version: LATEST
```

Use any value that you will deem appropriate instead of `LATEST`. Available values are the names of constants in `org.apache.lucene.util.Version`.

See also [the documentation about this specific topic in Hibernate Search](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#_index_format_compatibility).

**Update**

In Hiberante Search 6 this property has become:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.backend.lucene_version=LATEST
```

See also [the documentation about this specific topic in Hibernate Search 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_index_format_compatibility).

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to create `hibernate.properties` file in the classpath (I placed it beside my application.properties file) and insert `hibernate.search.lucene_version LATEST` in it.